Precision perplexity: how to get all the decimal places to show up
If I want to see 50 digits of precision, I turn to the N function:
Like N[2/3, 50 gives me 0.66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667. Great!
But N[10000.3 + .85, 50] gives me 10001.2. Not great!
I can do InputForm[10000.3 + .85] to see that the real answer is 10001.15.
But it seems like N should do that too, right?

Numbers with only a few digits after the decimal point are MachinePrecision and can't be directly extended to 50 digits of precision. Is this acceptable? N[Rationalize[10000.3] +Rationalize[.85], 50] returns 10001.149999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999950TheRationalizeattempts to turn those into exact rationals which then can be used withN` to get your desired 50 digit precision.

to get arbitrary precision you need to add the backtick. here is screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/O9W7NSA1.png

Use 10000.3`50  instead of 10000.3. It tells mathematica that the precision of your number is 50.
N[10000.3`50 + .85`50, 50]
(*10001.150000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*)

